# How to enable multiple row selections in angular js table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am able to select multiple rows, but I would like to be able to select those datas in different tables on the same page. At the  moment, when I select a row in the first table, it selects it in the second table as well, but I would like them to be independent. Anyone has an idea ?

**Below is my html code**

```
<div class="row" ng-show="{{ adultNumber }}">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>Adult 1</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr ng-repeat="extra in extras" ng-class="{'selected': extra.selected}" ng-click="select(extra)" ng-model="radioExtrasAdult1">
                <td ng-bind="extra.name"></td>
                <td ng-bind="extra.price"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-show="{{ adultNumber >= 2 }}">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h1>Adult 2</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr ng-repeat="extra in extras" ng-class="{'selected': extra.selected}" ng-click="select(extra)" ng-model="radioExtrasAdult2">
                <td ng-bind="extra.name"></td>
                <td ng-bind="extra.price"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Below angular js**

```
$http.get('json/extras.json')
    .then(function(res){
        $scope.extras = res.data;                
    });

$scope.select = function(item) {
    item.selected ? item.selected = false : item.selected = true;
}

$scope.submit = function(x) {
    var x = $filter("filter")($scope.extras, {
        selected: true
    }, true);
    console.log(x);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the relationship between adultNumber and extras?

Comment: Is that ok that you show both tables at the same time, or there should be `ng-show=" adultNumber == 1"` for Adult 1?

Comment: @lukaZawi yes it is ok, it is on purpose. adultNumber is just a data I treat in the controller to make a condition. It is not linked with my problem, I think.

Comment: So do you want to store information which rows where selected in first table and which rows where selected in second table?

Comment: In separate ones (`radioExtrasAdult1`, `radioExtrasAdult2`) or in `extras` (`extra.selected1` and `extra.selected2`)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, when you select an object in a table, you modify its attribute to tell it it is selected. Given the fact that you are using the same object in the other table, it is updated too and so it is also selected.

There are different things you can do about it,

1. Make a deep copy of the objects you display so that you display one copy per table and so you don't modify the two contents simultaneously. For this, use **angular.copy**.
2. Modify different attributes on the same object when performing selection. You could for instance use **item.selected[0]** for the first table and **item.selected[1]** for the second one. The advantage of this solution is that all data is centralized in the same object. Still, you have to pass an aditional parameter to your select function to tell in which table you are selecting (**0** or **1**)

Hope it helped !